# Is there any open-source or freeware to convert entire Visual Foxpro Database into mysql?

Tags: mysql, converters, database-migration, visual-foxpro

I have tried some online converters but they are only converting like 50 records from one table. Is there any tool or a proper way to migrate Visual Foxpro Data into mysql data?

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of utilities on the [Leafe.com](http://leafe.com/dls/vfp) site that might help.

> VFPData2MariaScript   Use this script to create a set of INSERT records that detects the structure of your VFP tables. This works well with the utility of STRU2MYSQL_2.PRG which scripts a CREATE TABLE file. This may work for PostgreSQL as well as MariaDB and MySQL. Note that if your table is really large, you may run into execution limits, or file size limits. There is another utility that opens up a connection from VFP and upsizes the data. This utility just creates a script of INSERT statements that you run through phpMyAdmin or the like. Author: Kevin Cully